# Mailitem doesn't provide any information about the sender

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I tried the following:

```
var x = mailItem.Sender;
var y = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress;
var z = mailItem.SenderName;
```

All three variables have the value null. This the mailItem being edited in the ispector and I can access all other iformation like receptients, etc....
Any clue as to how get the sender name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is even better and works anywhear:

```
MailItem.SendUsingAccount.SmtpAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me:

```
Outlook.NameSpace ns = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.Recepient CurrentUser = ns.CurrentUser;
```

I don't know yet what would happen if the user has multiple accounts.